# Automating Notepad++ macros

Tags: macros, notepad++

I've created a macro that parses reports generated from an Access DB, Database Documenter tool.

I have multiple reports I want to run this on, but even though I've opened multiple reports within Notepad++, I can only run it on one report at a time.

When I recorded the macro, I didn't select **Replace All in All Opened Documents**.

Is there a change in **Shortcuts.xml** I can make that will cause the macro to run on all the open docs?

I have recorded other macros, where I did select **Replace All in All Opened Documents**, But I have seen no difference between those ones and the one I just worked on.

I have 60 documents and the macro has 125 steps.

Your help would be greatly appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I did some playing around with macros and here's what I've come up with.

The "Replace All" button click is represented by these two lines in `shortcuts.xml`:

```
<Action type="3" message="1702" wParam="0" lParam="768" sParam="" />
<Action type="3" message="1701" wParam="0" lParam="1609" sParam="" />
```

The "Replace All in All Open Documents" click is represented by these two lines:

```
<Action type="3" message="1702" wParam="0" lParam="0" sParam="" />
<Action type="3" message="1701" wParam="0" lParam="1635" sParam="" />
```

If you look for those first two lines in your `shortcuts.xml` file, you should be able to replace them with the last two and have it work.  I'd make a backup of your shortcuts file before doing so though.  Just in case.

Comment: Awesome! I just ran the macro on all the tables. Thanks.

Comment: Glad to help.  Please consider marking the question as solved by [accepting an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) to help out future readers.